# How to Add Items to Spinner?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

This is what i am doing right now

```
Spinner AddressTypeSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner1);


ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, new ProfileAddressTypes[] 
{ 

    for (var i = 0; i < AddressObject.Count; i++) 
    {
        new ProfileAddressTypes (AddressObject[i].id, AddressObject[i].name); 
    }
});

AddressTypeSpinner.Adapter = spinnerArrayAdapter;
```

This doe not work it says cant to put for inside the Array Adapter

I have no idea on how to do this anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,mArrayListspinner);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        AddressTypeSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

here **mArrayListspinner** is your string array.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProfileAddressTypes[] mList = new ProfileAddressTypes[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   mList[i]= new ProfileAddressTypes (AddressObject[i].id, AddressObject[i].name);        
}

ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this, R.id_from_your_layout_of_that_activity_or_fragment, mList);  
yourSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter );
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, GetAdapterData());

public ProfileAddressTypes[] GetAdapterData()
{
    var adapterData = new ProfileAddressTypes[AddressObject.Count];

    for (var i = 0; i < AddressObject.Count; i++) 
    {
        adapterData[i] = new ProfileAddressTypes (AddressObject[i].id, AddressObject[i].name); 
    }
    return adapterData;
}
```

Or using `List<T>` instead and calling `ToArray()` at the end:

```
 public ProfileAddressTypes[] GetAdapterData()
 {
      var adapterData = new List<ProfileAddressTypes>();

      for (var i = 0; i < AddressObject.Count; i++) 
      {
          adapterData.Add(new ProfileAddressTypes (AddressObject[i].id, AddressObject[i].name)); 
      }
      return adapterData.ToArray();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in `ArrayAdapter` constructor not array but object that implements interface  `IList`, for example `List<ProfileAddressTypes>`, besides for correct output you should override method `ToString()`.

Here's my code:

```
Spinner modelSelect = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.modelSelect);
List<Marks> models = (from i in DBHelper.GetInstance().Table<Marks>() where i.removed == false orderby i.name ascending select i).ToList();
modelSelect.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Marks>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, models);
```

And a part of class `Models`:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return name;
}
```